# user account used as a service account

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, service

I have a user who has set up a few services running on their domain user account - the problem is that he doesn't remember where he set his account up like this. Is there anyway to see what his account is linked to without just disabling the account and waiting for someone to shout?

There is a high chance that the services linked to his account could cause service outages to several users

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for where he set the service to run under a particular user account (try the services control panel) or where he granted his user account "Logon as a Service" privileges? (see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a6fcbe72-6f75-4bd2-bb96-440e2c8913c2/how-do-i-configure-a-user-account-to-have-logon-as-a-service-permissions?forum=winserverGP)

Answer (score 1):

Run a PowerShell command like this on all your servers:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_service | Where-Object {$_.StartName -notmatch "^(LocalSystem|NT Authority)" -and $_.ServiceType -ne "Unknown"} | Format-Table Name, StartName -auto
```

or if you know the actual name of the account:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_service | Where-Object StartName -match "username" | Format-Table Name, StartName -auto
```

this will show all services not run by the usual suspects, or actually run under the domain account in question.